# How to disable cookies in firebase analytics

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I use firebase analytics (the SDK not google analytics with gtag) for my website and i would like to propose to user to accept or not cookies and i don't know how to disable firebase analytics when users press decline.
Thx you and have a nice day.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I saw that to disable gtag it’s like that: 
window['ga-disable-GA_MEASUREMENT_ID'] = true;
But i don't know if it's working for firebase analytics